# Problems with getBytes, if leftmost bit is 1, next bit is always 0

Tags: java, ascii

I have after a lot of troubleshooting managed to get an encoder and decoder workin where I input a number, it turns it into binary and then ASCII, returns that, I feed that into the other one, it turns the ASCII into binary and then strings that toghether into a number. This works for all numbers that do not look like 11xx xxxx as they turn into 10xx xxxx.

Encoder:

```
public static String convert(int number) {
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(number);
    String string = "";
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

    while (binary.length() < 32) {
        binary = "0" + binary;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        string += (char) Integer.parseInt(binary.substring(i * 8, (i + 1) * 8), 2);
    }

    return string;
}
```

Decoder:

```
public static int convert(String message) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[message.length()];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            bytes[i] = (message.substring(i, i + 1).getBytes("UTF-8"[message.substring(i, i + 1).getBytes("UTF-8").length - 1]);
        }
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder(32);
        String s;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            s = Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i] & 0xFF);
            while (s.length() < 8)
                s = "0" + s;
            binary.append(s);
        }
        int result = 0;
        result = Integer.parseInt(binary.toString(), 2);
        return result;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood what character encoding does. Throw out everything with getBytes() in the decoder.

getBytes() *encodes to* UTF-8, which is *not one byte per character*. If you encoded one byte per character in encoder, you decode one byte per *character* in the decoder.

You encoder is treacherously convoluted btw. The simple version would be to directly decompose the int into bytes and cast to char:

```
String encode(int i) {
    char[] result = new char[4];
    char[0] = (char) (i >>> 24);
    char[1] = (char) ((i >> 16) & 0xFF);
    char[2] = (char) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF);
    char[3] = (char) (i & 0xFF);
    return new String(result);
}
```

The decoder can be much simpler as well:

```
int decode(String s) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<s.length; ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c > 255)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid character: " + c);
        result = (result << 8) | (c & 0xFF);
    }
    return result;
}
```

All you intermediate conversions achieve nothing but make the code more confusing and error prone.